# Get input values of a form hidden in Jquery with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a bit of a problem here (or big I actually don't know) I'm new with PHP and I want to know if is possible to get the values of a form input field with PHP that are appended with Jquery is an user choose the right option.

The thing is I'm getting all the values in all the input fields that are previously loaded on the page. All the values are required in order to submit the form, but the thing is that the fields that are appended in the form (with Jquery) when the user chooses and option of a select field aren't being processed by PHP and I can't access their values.

So basically: If the user doesn't select any number (0 by default) the fields don't appear and they are not required to fill in, although, if the user select "1 to 10" in the select input the amount of input fields appear and the NEED to be filled in to submit the form.. how can I achieve that?

Here is the code

This is the PHP code I have before the DOCTYPE in the php form page:

```
$errores = [];
$faltantes = [];

if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && (isset($_POST['continue']))) :

  $expected = ['nombres', 'apellidos', 'cedula_tipo', 'cedula_no', 'fecha_nacimiento', 'sexo', 'edad', 'civil', 'direccion', 'ciudad', 'pais', 'tel_hab', 'tel_cel', 'email', 'plan', 'pago', 'beneficiarios'];
  $requeridos = ['nombres', 'apellidos', 'cedula_tipo', 'cedula_no', 'fecha_nacimiento', 'sexo', 'edad', 'civil', 'direccion', 'ciudad', 'pais', 'tel_hab', 'tel_cel', 'email', 'plan', 'pago', 'beneficiarios'];

  require './includes/tdaform_process1test.php';

  if (!$errores && !$faltantes) :

  endif;

endif;
```

This is the form field where the user selects and based on his selection the other inputs appear:

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" id="planilla_tda" name="planilla_tda">

        <div class="bene-select">
          <h4>Puedes agregar beneficiarios a tu plan.</h4>
          <label for="beneficiarios">Cantidad de beneficiarios</label>
            <select name="beneficiarios" id="beneficiariosCount">
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
        </div>

        <div id="beneficiarios" class="beneficiarios"></div>

        <button type="submit" class="btn-contacto" name="continue" value="submit">enviar planilla</button>
      </form>
```

This is the DIV (that contains the input fields) that is appending when the user makes a selection other than "0":

```
<div class="beneficiario-wrap">
  <label for="nombre_bene">Nombre y Apellido</label>
    <input type="text" name="nombre_bene[]" value="">
  <label for="cedulabene_no">Cedula beneficiario</label>
  <div>
    <select name="cedulabene_tipo">
      <option value="Venezolano" selected>V </option>
      <option value="Extranjero">E </option>
    </select> <input type="text" name="cedulabene_no[]" value="" maxlength="8">
  </div>
  <label for="edad_bene">Edad beneficiario</label>
  <input type="text" name="edad_bene[]" value="">
</div>
```

This is how I'm appending the input fields with Jquery:

```
const divToAppend = '<div class="beneficiario-wrap"><label for="nombre_bene">Nombre y Apellido</label><input type="text" name="nombre_bene" value=""><label for="nombre_bene">Cedula beneficiario</label><div><select name="cedulabene_tipo"><option value="Venezolano" selected>V </option><option value="Extranjero">E </option></select> <input type="text" name="cedulabene_no" value="" maxlength="8"></div><label for="edad_bene">Edad beneficiario</label><input type="text" name="edad_bene" value=""></div>';


     let number = $('#beneficiarios').val();

  $('#beneficiariosCount').on('change', function () {
    $('#beneficiarios').html('');
    number = $(this).val();
    for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
      $('#beneficiarios').append(divToAppend);
    }
  });
```

and this is how I'm looping through all the the fields and make them require with PHP:

```
    $suspect = false;
$emailPattern = '/Content-type:|Bcc:|Cc:/i';

function isSuspect ($value, $emailPattern, &$suspect) {
  if (is_array($value)) :
      foreach ($value as $item) {
        isSuspect($item, $emailPattern, $suspect);
      }
  else :
      if (preg_match($emailPattern, $value)) {
          $suspect = true;
      }
  endif;
}

isSuspect($_POST, $emailPattern, $suspect);

if (!$suspect) :
  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $value = is_array($value) ? $value : trim($value);

    if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $requeridos)) {
        $faltantes[] = $key;
        $$key = '';
    } elseif (in_array($key, $expected)) {
        $$key = $value;
      }
  }

  endif;
```

As I said I'm really new with PHP and I came out with this approach with self-education. So, Please help!

Comment: $$key = ''; ?? doble $$ and  $$key = $value;

Comment: To send an array of data to PHP add `[]` to you input names. E.g. `<input name="nombre_bene[]" />`

Comment: I already have it that way.. all the input fields that are appended are named as an array.